# Angular REST Data from service to component

Tags: angular, rest, angular7

I need help figuring out why my data isn't populating in the HTML. I'm sure it's something dumb but I can't figure it out. And I apologize if I left anything out and will gladly include it.

Below is the console results:

```
undefined
core.js:13606 Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
```

below is the JSON i'm GETting through postman:

GET: http://localhost:3000/api/posts/

```
{
    "postName": "Fun in the Sun",
    "postDate": "10/23/1993",
    "caption": "Hear all about my trip to lalaland",
    "mainImage": "https://placeholder.net/20x20",
    "suppementalImage1": "https:// placeholder.net/20x20",
    "suppementalImage2": "https:// placeholder.net/20x20",
    "suppementalImage3": "https:// placeholder.net/20x20",
    "suppementalImage4": "https:// placeholder.net/20x20",
    "suppementalImage5": "https:// placeholder.net/20x20",
    "suppementalImage6": "https:// placeholder.net/20x20",
    "content": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates deleniti quas dolorem quis nulla debitis praesentium dolores eveniet aliquam! At expedita vel consequatur, sit laboriosam ducimus molestiae recusandae ipsam sunt.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates deleniti quas dolorem quis nulla debitis praesentium dolores eveniet aliquam! At expedita vel consequatur, sit laboriosam ducimus molestiae recusandae ipsam sunt.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates deleniti quas dolorem quis nulla debitis praesentium dolores eveniet aliquam! At expedita vel consequatur, sit laboriosam ducimus molestiae recusandae ipsam sunt."
}
```

**posts.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable, Subject, asapScheduler, pipe, of, from, interval, merge, fromEvent, SubscriptionLike, PartialObserver } from 'rxjs';
import { Post } from '../models/post'
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators'
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PostsService {

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  private serverApi = 'http://localhost:3000';

  public getAllPosts(): Observable<Post[]> {
    let URI = `${this.serverApi}/api/posts/`;
    return this.http.get(URI)
      .pipe(map(res => res.json()))
      .pipe(map(res => <Post[]>res.posts));
  }

}
```

**latests-posts.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { PostsService } from '../services/posts.service';
import { Post } from '../models/post';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-latest-posts',
  templateUrl: './latest-posts.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./latest-posts.component.css']
})
export class LatestPostsComponent implements OnInit {
  private posts: Post[] = []; //creats a private variable of posts with type of model List an creates an empty array
  constructor(private postServ: PostsService) { };

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadPosts()
    console.log(this.loadPosts()); //loads all lists on init
  };

  public loadPosts() {
    this.postServ.getAllPosts().subscribe(response => this.posts = response)
  };


}
```

**latest-posts.component.html**

```
<table id="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Priority Level</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Description</th>

      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let post of posts">
        <td>{{post.name}}</td>
        <td>{{post.date}}</td>
        <td>{{posts.caption}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: Can you post what you console showing for `this.posts` after subscribe?

Comment: I updated it with the console from localhost:4200, sorry about that

Comment: Is response of `http://localhost:3000/api/posts/` the object? response look like `{ posts: [] }` based on your code

Comment: yes it should be the response of http://localhost:3000/api/posts/

Comment: You should log console.log(this.posts()); //loads all lists on init. Not this.loadPosts().

Comment: Just in order to debug try this in your template file `.html` `{{posts | json}}`

Comment: Your 'posts' property should not be private. Also, try making your posts property an Observable of posts like your API (posts: Observable<Post[]> = of([]), and then just assign that property to the api call (this.posts = this.postServ.getAllPosts).  Change your template ngFor to 'let post of posts | async'.  Additionally, make sure the API response is actually an array of posts and not some other structure.

Comment: @Kevin but `this.post()` is not function, it array type. IMP one should console in the subscribe part not in init as this is asynconour call, right?

Comment: @PardeepJain I added this to the html but doesn't show anything

Comment: yes @JaimeMoncayo that's the point buddy, your data is not binding properly. debug that in your `.ts` file, also make it `posts` public not private

Comment: We cant see the  localhost:3000/api/posts as it is served on your local system. It would be better to show your response object entirely or post your code on stackblitz to get your issue resolved soon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your API results there is no property with name "posts", though you have applied pipe to map res.posts, which will give you undefined.

Instead, you should return only `json` from service.

**Example: posts.service.ts**

```
public getAllPosts(): Observable<any> {
    let URI = `${this.serverApi}/api/posts/`;
    return this.http.get(URI)
      .pipe(map(res => res.json()));
  }
```

If you want to type cast your data at component, you can define its type at the time of subscribing it. like below.

**component.ts**

```
public loadPosts() {
    this.postServ.getAllPosts().subscribe((response: Post[]) => {
       if(Array.isArray(response))
          this.posts = response
       else {
          this.posts = [];
          this.posts.push(response);
       }
    })
 }
```

Comment: This is the closest answer so far. By changing the service and using   {{posts | json}} in the html I'm able to see the response in the HTML but it is not being picked up in the ngFor statement and I am seeing the following errors:

Comment: LatestPostsComponent.html:11 ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
    at NgForOf.push../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/common.js.NgForOf.ngDoCheck (common.js:3161)

Comment: and type casting in the component highlights Posts[] in red saying 
"Cannot find name Posts"

Comment: You can import `import { Post } from '../models/post';` to avoid that

Comment: Shreeni it is imported, the code in latests-posts.component.ts is above. I think the issue might be 
`export class LatestPostsComponent implements OnInit {
  public posts: Post[];` let me know your thoughts

Comment: Can you create one stackblitz demo?.. So i can help you better. you can start editing here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yrzgns

Comment: Sorry that was just a bad model on my part I figured it out! It's working perfectly now thank you so much. Would it be too much to ask for you to explain your solution and the logic behind it?

Comment: As explained in answer you were trying to return `res.posts` which was undefined in your case. So this code of `posts.service.ts` just returns whatever you fetch from API. And on component i have checked if the response is Array then directly assign it to `this.posts` and if its not array but single object than we are pushing it in `this.posts` which is array by default

Answer (score 1):

The API call is an async function and need time to resolve. It's missing an `ngif` in the HTML, so the DOM is updated, when the data arrives.

Something like

```
<div *ngIf="posts.length > 0"> Content to render when condition is true.</div>
```